# Ruby compiling error ‘__NR_statx’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install a version of Ruby 2.7.8 using RVM. Gives an error when compiling.

**Compile log:**

```
file.c:1176:1: error: static declaration of ‘statx’ follows non-static declaration
 statx(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags,
 ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:446:0,
                 from ./include/ruby/defines.h:131,
                 from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:29,
                 from ./include/ruby/encoding.h:27,
                 from file.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/statx.h:87:5: note: previous declaration of ‘statx’ was here
 int statx (int __dirfd, const char *__restrict __path, int __flags,
     ^~~~~
file.c: In function ‘statx’:
file.c:1179:25: error: ‘__NR_statx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     return (int)syscall(__NR_statx, dirfd, pathname, flags, mask, statxbuf);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
file.c:1179:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:420: recipe for target 'file.o' failed
make: *** [file.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

**OS:** Debian 10

**RVM:** 1.29.10

Tell me what this problem can be connected with? I thought the problem is openssl, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `man statx`: "This function returns information about a file, storing it in the buffer pointed to by statxbuf.". It's used by the File class and is built into most unix systems. Not sure why its failing to build.